# Programmatic file upload with jQuery-File-Upload

Tags: jquery-file-upload

I use jQuery-File-Upload plugin for uploading the images. now I create an image from canvas und would like to use the same mechanismus to transfer this image to the server. 
In jQuery-File-Upload documentation I found the way to use the fileUpload component programatically but it expects the list of files as parameters

```
     $('#fileupload').fileupload('send', {files: filesList});
```

in my case I have the image in form of base64.

```
       var image = canvas.toDataURL();
```

how can I use fileUpload component to transfer my canvas image?

Comment: I would like to do the same as what you are doing. Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Just send it as POST data, then on the server side  decode it from Base64 and save it as a png ( which I think is the default type ) but the mime-type of the file will be at the start of the base-64!

Comment: sure, I can send it as POST, but I have another logic inside of "done" function of fileUpload which I would like to reuse for my canvas image.

Comment: If you want to dispaly the canvas image somewhere on your page, you can stick the output of the canvas.toDataURL(); into the src attribute of an img tag.

Comment: it's everything understandable what you write. thanks.
I just want to know if its possible to use filesUpload component in my case and not to write another code for the same case