# jQuery File Upload Plugin https://blueimp.net

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

Good evening,
I would like to use the plugin jQuery File Upload Plugin but I have a problem.
I'm using a base64 image, because the image passes through a trimming tool to cut the image.
How can I upload and upload an image in base64 format via .fileupload ()
I need a jquery / php version

I can not find solutions, thanks in advance
Sincerely

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass Blob through ajax to generate a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015555/pass-blob-through-ajax-to-generate-a-file)

Comment: This might be an easier one to follow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34779799/upload-base64-image-with-ajax

Comment: I use this plugin
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki

You have an example to recover the blob with the function fileupload?
I only find examples via input fields
Thank you very much in any case for your express answer

Comment: I can actually with my trimming tool recover the image in blob but I can not find the example to pass it in the fileupload

Comment: Just google `jquery ajax post` or `jquery xhr`. Common question. Otherwise try plugin docs. Sorry, just noticing we are talking about some specific upload plugin. Seeing [this...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18210031/programmatic-file-upload-with-jquery-file-upload)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From their documentation: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API#programmatic-file-upload

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload('add', {files: filesList});
```

> The second argument must be an object with an array (or array-like
>   list) of File or Blob objects as files property.

So sounds like it is as simple as:

```
var blob = ... //you said in the comments you've got the blob...
var blob = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';
$('#fileupload').fileupload('add', {files: [blob]})
```

Now, I've also come across some more complex code ([source](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Upload-directly-to-S3)) that suggests something like this is also possible:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    autoUpload: true,
    add: function (event, data) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/upload",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {doc: {title: data.files[0].name}},
        async: false,
        success: function(response) {
          ...
        }

      });
```

Seems pretty flexible.

Comment: What I do not understand is $ ('# fileupload') being given that it is a blob and name an object of the DOM html so I do not see how to adapt it.

Comment: Sorry I'm new: D

Comment: If I understand... you said you have a variable with a base64 string that is an image. Why are we talking about the DOM? This is trying to illustrate that you can pass that `blob` just as you would the file uploaded to a form's file input.

Comment: If we look at $ ('# fileupload'). Fileupload ('add', {files: [blob]}) we can see that the function fileupload is associated with an element of dom $ ('# fileupload').
I do not understand being given that goes through the blob so not an DOM object html.

Comment: Seems to me that the plugin takes a form element. `$ ('# fileupload)` is the form.

Comment: No it's an input field
Here is the demo example.
It's a file type input
http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic.html

Comment: In the data I can put my blob in your opinion? Here "data: {doc: {title: data.files[0].name}}," ?